# Lexical Errors:misspelling of keywords

Tags: lexical

In the dragon book it is mentioned that 
"Lexical errors include misspelling of identifiers,keywords,or operators"

I am a bit confused how will a lexical analyzer find a misspelling of keyword wont it consider the misspelled keyword as an identifier?

Comment: Yes, but the parser will now fail to parse. I guess they are a bit vague on what a lexical error mean. Typically in Scheme, a lexical error will fail right there and then (thus input is invalid, ie bad number, unknown characters, etc), but in the same scenario as you described, Scheme will report a syntax error due to it's failure to interpret the syntax.

Comment: Like @leppie said, the most likely error when a misspelled keyword is encountered is a parser error (parser found an identifier instead of a keyword for example). If you make your own compiler, you can of course suggest keywords similar to the misspelled word in the error message, akin to Google search "did you mean..." when you misspell a word when searching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lexical Errors: misspelling of identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645475/lexical-errors-misspelling-of-identifiers)