# Errors in compiler construction (lexical, syntax and semantic error)

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-construction

I have a good knowledge of semantic, syntax and lexical error in compiler but i don't understand that how we can identify the all three errors in piece of code. As some resources say that spelling checking is lexical error and some say its a syntax error so i am confused. Kindly help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly are you asking? Please review [how to ask a good stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: These distinctions are arbitrary and have little or no theoretical basis. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69650478/1566221